# How can an improper integral have a finite value

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, intuition

How is it possible for an improper integral to have a finite value? For example, an integral that has infinity as its upper bound and has the horizontal asymptote y=0. I understand that one can arrive at a finite value by taking the limit. However, when thinking about this visually, if a function goes on until infinity, then how can the area under it be finite? What is the physical difference between taking the limit and summing the area under the graph until infinity?

Comment: Are you OK with the idea of an infinite series summing to a finite value, such as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$?

Comment: It might contradict your intuition, but it will help if you look at the definition of an improper integral, where the limit-sign is involved.

Comment: Consider for example $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}/2 dx$. If you look at the "sub-integrals" $\int_{2^{-2n}}^1 x^{-1/2}/2 dx$ ($n=1,2,\dots$) you see that each one is finite and they are $1-2^{-n}$. Each of these is just the integral over the region where $f$ is no more than $2^{n}$, so they're of course each finite. The area you ignored is then small for large $n$ because even though you can fit very tall rectangles in there, they have to be very thin; their thickness must be not just small but *much smaller than the reciprocal of their height*. (After that, you have to accept Zeno's paradox to finish.)

Comment: You can contrast that with $\int_0^1 x^{-1} dx$ where you can fit in rectangles whose thickness is the same as the reciprocal of their height, so their area doesn't become small.

Comment: Sorry, what I said was about the case of unbounded functions on a bounded interval rather than bounded functions on an unbounded interval. But you can interchange the role of thickness and height to complete the analogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eyeballfrog notes in the comments, you may find it helpful to think of the intuition for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}=1.$$ Visually, this says that if you fill a glass half full, then fill half of the empty space remaining, then fill half of the empty space remaining, etc. you will approach filling one glass. Despite infinitely many fills, we have a finite volume in the limit because intuitively each fill introduces sufficiently less volume than the preceding fill (with vanishing volume in the limit).

A continuous analogue of the above series is the improper integral

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=1.$$

Again, as with cup filling, though integrating over an infinite interval, $e^{-x}$ vanishes sufficiently quickly in the limit for the integral to be convergent.

The above improper integral has an integrand with a horizontal asymptote. An improper integral whose integrand has a vertical asymptote may be thought of much the same way; just think of the integrand as a function with a horizontal asymptote that has been rotated 90 degrees.